# how to know tableview size xcode iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, resize, tableview

```
- (double) tableSize
{
    double tableSize1=[self tableView:tableViewA numberOfRowsInSection:0]*tableViewA.rowHeight;
    return tableSize1;
}
```

I use that code to know tablesize, but I want to know easier way to know it.. like tableviewA.size or something like that..

example : tableviewA have 20 tableviewcell, I want to know the tableviewA size.. how to know it?

If I do tableViewA.frame.size.height it'll always show 400, which is the height of the table frame, because that's the size of the table view. I want the size of the whole table including those I need to scroll. –

For example, if the tableviewA has lots of rows then I want to see a high number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this - `tableView.contentSize.height`

Answer (score 1):

this help?

```
tableView.frame.size.height
```

or

```
tableView.frame.size.width
```

then may be you can use

```
CGSize tableViewContentSize = tableView.contentSize;
```

to get the content size.

then to get the height and width just

```
tableViewContentSize.height
tableViewContentSize.width
```

Comment: If I do this, it'll always show 400 because that's the size of the table view. I want the size of the whole table including those I need to scroll.

Comment: how about (table cell height x number of cells)? sounds reasonable?